# Annular ring pattern with alternate bright and dark rings: using matlab

Tags: matlab

I am attempting to make a pattern consisting of annular rings with radii proportional to the square root of the natural numbers. Also I want the inner most circle to be white followed by a black circle followed by a white and so on.

```
c = [0 0; 0 0];
r = [5.2494 9.0922];
viscircles(c, r)
r1 = [7.4328 10.4988];
viscircles(c, r1)
```

I have generated the above code to form the annular ring structure but I want to fill in the color as well. What should I do?

Answer (score 7):

You could go the mathematical route and plot the function `ceil(sin(pi*(X.^2 + Y.^2)))`:

```
zoomlevel = 50;
for n = 1:zoomlevel
    [X,Y] = ndgrid(linspace(-n,n,500));
    I = ceil(sin(pi*(X.^2 + Y.^2)));
    imshow(mat2gray(I));
    drawnow;
    pause(0.03);
end
```

Of course this will only be a raster graphic instead of a vector one, so don't zoom in too much. ;-) (Although the aliasing artefacts will look quite cool if you zoom *out*. Plot at your own risk.)
[image: Circles]

Comment: HOLY ****! That aliasing artefacts look amazing!

Comment: @AnderBiguri I could do some astral projection stuff on this!! ;)

Comment: Let's see who can stare at _this_ for more than 1 minute!! :-P

Comment: I'd love to see how this is rendered in R2014b (I don't have it at the moment). The aliasing artifacts should be smaller (see for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27639907/2586922))

Comment: @LuisMendo: I don't have it either, but I've already seen some interesting smooth 3D stuff on: [Alec Jacobson's blog](http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=4094). Such smooth plots directly from MATLAB are quite new to me...

Comment: @knedlsepp Yeah, they have definitely improved graph rendering. And the new default colormap looks nice

Comment: @LuisMendo I tried. Looks equally hallucinogenic in 2014b.

Comment: @AnderBiguri But isn't the aliasing smaller? Aren't the spurious circles (those other than the central one) fainter?

Comment: @LuisMendo I haven't looked that deeply, but in a single glance it looks the same. I will try to save it whenever I have time (dont have 2014b now, even if i did 4 minutes ago).

Comment: @LuisMendo: Thinking about this a bit the anti-aliasing should come into play only in yours or *Hoki*'s answer. As I am basically manually evaluating the function without any supersampling and plotting an image the results should be the same across all versions of MATLAB. (Given that we view the image at full resolution)

Comment: @knedlsepp Well, R2014b is supposed to have [improved anti-aliasing](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics-changes-in-r2014b.html). But, like Ander, I don't see noticeable differences in R2014b

Comment: @LuisMendo: Yes, but in this case there won't be any anti-aliasing involved (as long as you don't shrink down the image) because `imshow` will simply show the `500x500` pixels in `I`. There might however be a difference in your vector graphics. Following your notation in the question linked earlier: This is exclusively aliasing of the first kind.

Comment: @knedlsepp Do you mean anti-aliasing is only applied in vector graphics (such as lines) and not in "bitmap-based" ones (images)? But if the image size doesn't match screen size there has to be some interpolation involved, right?

Comment: @LuisMendo: Yes, I think we both mean the same thing. I simply guessed that your screen resolution will be high enough to show the `500-by-500` pixels image, so there won't be any interpolation occurring.

Comment: I've stared at this animated .gif for probably 5 minutes. +1.

Comment: @rayryeng: All glory to the hypnotoad! It seems those gifs are also great for sneaking some rep... ;-)

Comment: Hehe yes I'd know. I'd give you +10 for the futurama reference.

Answer (score 4):

My Matlab version doesn't have `viscircles`,  so here's an approach which plots each individual circle with alternating colors. It uses the [`rectangle`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rectangle.html) function, which lets you define the curvature of the corners so that the rectangle/square becomes an ellipse/circle. Bigger circles should be drawn first, so that they don't completely cover smaller circles.

```
colors = [.9 .9 .9; 0 0 0]; %// light gray and black
N = 16; %// maximum number
hold on
for n = N:-1:1; %// bigger circles first
    s = sqrt(n);
    rectangle('curvature', [1 1], 'position', [-s/2 -s/2 s s], ...
        'edgecolor', 'none', 'facecolor', colors(mod(n-1,2)+1,:));
end
axis square
```

[image]

Comment: Matlab can be confusing. How to draw a lot of circles? What about the `rectangle` function! ...

Comment: yep ... definitely the most intuitive way to draw a circle. +1 for a good twisting of Matlab's arm.

Comment: @Hoki @Ander Totally agree. Who would have thought of using `rectangle` for drawing circles?

Answer (score 3):

You can also create a "surface" with value `1` for all your `r` radiuses and `0` for the `r1`. Then either plot as a surface seen form top, or directly use `pcolor`.

```
r = [0 5.2494 7.4328 9.0922 10.4988] ;  %// define all your radiuses
bw = mod( 1:numel(r) , 2 ) ;            %// create an alternance of 0 and 1 (same size as "r")
ntt = 50 ;                              %// define how many angular division for the plot
theta = linspace(0,2*pi,ntt) ;          %// create all the angular divisions
[rr,tt]=meshgrid(r,theta) ;             %// generate a grid 

z = repmat( bw , ntt , 1 ) ;            %// replicate our [0 1 0 ...] vector to match the grid

[xx,yy,zz] = pol2cart(tt,rr,z) ;        %// convert everything to cartesian coordinates

pcolor(xx,yy,zz)                        %// plot everything
colormap(gray(2))                       %// make sure we use only 2 colors (black and white)
shading flat ; axis equal               %// refine the view (axis ratio and "spokes" not visible)
```

You can send as many radiuses as you like in the original `r`.
This will render:

[image: alternatecircles]

This method look a bit longer at first than other solution, but you could remove many intermediate steps by consolidating some lines, and if you are to reuse the graphics later on, it may present 2 benefits:

- if you get the handle of the graphic object (`hp=pcolor(xx,yy,zz)`), you only have **one** graphic object to handle.
- if you need to change the color, you do not need to cycle through each circle, just change the colormap to the 2 colors you want (for example if you want "red" and "green", just call the colormap `colormap([1 0 0;0 1 0])` and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

`viscircles` returns an `hggroup` object. One of the properties of such an object is its `Children`, which is an array of handles to the graphics objects it creates. For instance you could write

```
h1 = viscircles(c, r)
c1 = h1.Children
```

The children here should just be the handles to the circular patches defined by `viscircles`. Now, to set the color of the `i`th circular patch, you can set the `FaceColor` property of the handle `c1(i)`.

Comment: I guess this is more helpful than my answer.